# TTThumbsViewController / TTPhotoView - Change Caption Size?

Tags: iphone, three20

I am working with Three20's PhotoTest2Controller (TTThumbsViewController).  When I click a thumbnail and open the image (TTPhotoView?), how can I increase the size of the caption area?  I need to be able to display more than 6 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caption uses a default TTStyle to render itself (see [source](http://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/06f4b4e794cfd123c8a1d4da87cec41e7c38d05a/src/TTPhotoView.m), line 57) so all you have to do is register a stylesheet, and override the method `photoCaption` so that `TTSTYLE(photoCaption)` uses your method instead of the one found in the `TTDefaultStylesheet`

Comment: Thanks. That does help. Unfortunately, I do not have a lot of experience overriding methods. Where do I override photoCaption?  Currently, I only imported PhotoTest2Controller (TTThumbsViewController) and MockPhotoSource (TTPhotoSource) into my project. Can I get to photoCaption through one of these, or do I need to import/edit TTPhotoView? Thanks in advance!